# Ubuntu VPS: Can't connect to outside server (Github)

Tags: networking, github

I am setting up a VPS Ubuntu 20.04 that should host an RStudio instance and shiny-server.

It seems that I have trouble with connecting to outside servers, e.g. Github. I have set up a Git repository and wanted to test it:

```
git push -u origin master
fatal: konnte nicht auf 'https://github.com/***.git/' zugreifen: Couldn't connect to server
```

Similarly when I am trying to install an R library from Github.

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"devtools::install_github('***')\""
Fehler: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
Couldn't connect to server
```

I disabled the ufw, but no change. I am not very experienced and could need some pointers on what to check in order to resolve the issue.

Also: Not sure if related but installing RStudio server yields an error as well:

```
sudo rstudio-server verify-installation
ERROR system error 1 (Operation not permitted); OCCURRED AT rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::system::setResourceLimit(rstudio::core::system::ResourceLimit, RLimitType, RLimitType) src/cpp/core/system/PosixSystem.cpp:1485; LOGGED FROM: int main(int, char* const*) src/cpp/server/ServerMain.cpp:569
```

Answer (score 0):

Server is IPv6 which isn't supported by Github.

Comment: Please edit your answer and give some more information for others who may be facing the same problem. Did you fix it? How did you switch to IPv4 to make it work? Where is it stated that Github doesn't support IPv6? Etc.